# If b = a, why does b change after I redefine a in the next line?

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, operators

Can someone explain the difference between these two scenarios? Namely, why b was NOT redefined in the first but it WAS redefined in the second?

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4]
b = a           //b = [0,1,2,3,4]
a = 4     
console.log(b)  //b is still [0,1,2,3,4]
                //redefining a AFTER saying b = a will NOT change b
```

/

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4]
b = a           //b = [0,1,2,3,4]

for ( i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  a[a.length - (i + 1)] = b[i]  
}               //I though this loop would redefine a as b in reverse. But this happens: 

console.log(a)  //both a and b have changed to [0,1,2,1,0]
console.log(b)  //I don't understand why b changed at all, since a is being redefined
                //AFTER I saved b as [0,1,2,3,4] and the = sign is supposed to just
                //assign the value on the right to the value on the left
```

Comment: if you want to have the reverse of array "a" as mentioned in your comments you can use `b = a.reverse()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case you have stored the reference of a single array into two variables - `a` and `b`. Then you have changed `a`, which removes the reference and now contains `4`. After this you have only variable `b` referring to the array and **you can change the items of that array only via `b`**.

In the second case you again have two reference of a single array in the variables `a` and `b`. But when you do some work and change one item `a[a.length - (i + 1)] = b[i]`, this statement just goes through the reference and changes an item in the single array object, because `b` also refers to the same array, the same changes are visible through the variable `b`.

So this statement `a[a.length - (i + 1)] = b[i]` gets the item at `b[i]` and assigns it to the `a[a.length - (i + 1)]`, but this is equivalent also to the statement `b[b.length - (i + 1)]`.

In concise, you have same reference in the `a` and `b` and if you change the array via `a` it is changed also for `b`, because they refer to the same array.

If you want to change the first array and does not affect the second one, you need to create two separate arrays. You can do it via `slice` function or array spread operator (`[...a]`) or just call `a.reverse` to return reversed array.

```js
const a = [0,1,2,3,4];
const b = a.slice(); // splice returns a new array

for(let i = b.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   a[a.length - i - 1] = b[i];
}

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Or just call `reverse` function

```js
let a = [0,1,2,3,4];
let b = [...a];
a.reverse();

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Good answer, but you could add a note about how to shallow copy an array with slice or link to another question about copying arrays.

Comment: In sort when you are assigning `a=4` the new reference will be created and when you update the array element `a[i]=b[j]` will use same reference and update element.

Answer (score 1):

Understand it like this

**Case 1**

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

This is equivalent to

```
Ref#1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
a = Ref#1
```

When you do `b = a`, the that is equivalent to

```
b = Ref#1
```

and `a = 4` is equivalent to

```
Ref#2 = 4
a = ValOfRef#2
```

Now b still holds `Ref#1`, that is why it is still `[0,1,2,3,4]`. Please note primitive datatypes like `Number` in your case are `value` type and `Objects/Arrays` are refrence type.

**Case 2**

In this case you are looping throught `Ref#1` and modifying it at the same time, since both `a` and `b` holde `Ref#1`, that is why you are getting unexpected result. For getting expected result you have to break the refrence of `a` and `b`. The simplest way to do that in your case is to use `JSON.parse(JSON.strigify())`. See below

```js
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[a.length - (i + 1)] = b[i];
}

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```